# Process 'rumpostgreswk' running on linux and took 100% memory and CPU, where does it come from?

Tags: node.js, linux, postgresql, process, pm2

I have a question, I'm running a nodeJs server on a Digital Ocean droplet. I'm using pm2 for monitoring the application, everything looks fine. However suddenly, 100% of the CPU and memory were used by a process called **rumpostgreswk** [screenshot of process](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pvyL5.png). I killed the process but I don't know if it will come back again, as it happened during a night and was the first time. Can someone help me with this issue? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You probably have been hacked.

Comment: There is a RUM extension to postgresql, but 1) you don't mention using it, 2) it is a library that gets linked into postgreSQL, it doesn't have a standalone binary, 3) it wouldn't be running as root anyway, 4) it probably wouldn't be multithreaded either.  This is almost certainly a cryptominer installed by a hacker, which is using a fake process name as a decoy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should check the cron.

```
sudo crontab -u postgres -l
```